# Session scope CacheManager can't be used in @Cacheable. How to fix that?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have two Cache Managers with Singleton(this one is primary) and Session scopes. And I point that in class MyRepository I want to use "sessionBasedCache" through the following annotation on a method:

```
@Cacheable(value = "members", key = "#id.value()", cacheManager = "sessionBasedCache")
...
```

When"sessionBasedCache" invoked I'm getting the this exception:

```
setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute with name scopedTarget.epeSessionBasedCache
```

This is my configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "sessionBasedCache")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public CacheManager epeSessionBasedCacheManager() {
    return new GuavaCacheManager();
}
```

What I've already tried: if I use cache with the singleton scope, everything is fine. I looked through SimpleCacheManager, it default spring cache. And it doesn't implement Serializable.

Do you have any thoughts about what happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want a session-scoped cache? Just store results in the session then if you want that.

Comment: It's more readable, according to my system. Because there're other places that use singleton(global) cache

Comment: Well it won't work as it isn't serializable, things to be stored in the session need to be serializable. Also the fact that your cache-manager is session scoped doesn't mean the provided caches are session-scoped. That might depend on the cache manager implementation used and how that manages it caches.